# How do I represent object iteration in TypeScript using generics?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert the [eachr](https://github.com/bevry/eachr) package to TypeScript.

Here is the desired usage:

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 'str' }
iterateObject(obj, function(value, key) {
    if (key === 'a') console.log(value) // intellisense should know value is a number
    if (key === 'b') console.log(value) // intellisense should know value is a string
})
```

Here is the current implementation:

```
interface IteratorCallback<Subject, Key, Value> {
    (this: Subject, value: Value, key: Key, subject: Subject): void | false
}

function iterateObject<
    Subject extends object,
    Key extends keyof Subject,
    Value extends Subject[Key]
>(subject: Subject, callback: IteratorCallback<Subject, Key, Value>): Subject {
    for (const key in subject) {
        if (subject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const value = subject[key]
            if (callback.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return subject
}
```

However, that complains with:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type 'Subject[Extract]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Value'.
>     Type 'object[Extract]' is not assignable to type 'Value'. [2345]

---

If I change the generics too:

```
function iterateObject<
    Subject extends Record<Key, Value>,
    Key extends Extract<keyof Subject, string>,
    Value extends Subject[Key]
>
```

Then I get the following complaint:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type 'Extract' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Key'.
>     Type 'string & keyof Subject' is not assignable to type 'Key'.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Key'.
>         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Key'. [2345]

---

I can change it to this:

```
export function iterateObject<Key extends keyof any, Value>(
    subject: Record<Key, Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, Key, Value>
): typeof subject {
```

Which doesn't erorr, and makes value `string | number`, however I am not sure why that works and the others don't, nor do I know why it can't figure out that when `key === 'a'` then `value` should be `number`.

---

What am I missing here?

Comment: type guards will not impact the type og another variable.. this is just not supported .. are you open to  using a single object instead of two parameter ? We can do it with discriminated unions if there is a single parameter with a `key` and `value` properties.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir would you be interested in converting our bevry projects https://github.com/bevry to TypeScript for a fee/bounty? If so, please email me at b@bevry.me